# where do I get vm_area_struct for remap_pfn_range?

Tags: linux, arm, dma

I'm working with kernel 3.18 on ARM. I'm reading data from a camera for which I am writing the driver.
I use the following to set up the memory:

```
cpu_handle = dma_alloc_coherent(NULL, dma_size, &dma_handle, GFP_KERNEL | GFP_DMA);
```

This is working very well. I use the same kernel module to read out the memory after the camera has delivered the data and I can see the pictures.

Now I want to start a user space application to read the same data.
I think the way to go is `remap_pfn_range`.

I keep looking for examples but one thing they never describe is where I get the vm_area_struct from. I'm assuming this has to come from the user application right? For the first argument it says "user vma to map to". So how do I get a pointer to this structure?

Comment: If your driver allocated the buffer with `dma_alloc_coherent()`, it should implement `mmap()` requests for that buffer via `dma_mmap_coherent()`, not by calling `remap_pfn_range()` directly.

Comment: Thanks for this tip. dma_mmap_coherent seems to be the way to go on this.

Answer (score 1):

Looks like the vma pointer comes from the user space application.

Within the driver (kernel space) i had to create some methods, as well as a /dev file.

Then in the user application I opened the /dev file and I called mmap on it. This in turn invoked my own mmap method within my driver and the vma (vm_area_struct) was magically sent along.